# Mysql Join Won't Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been doing a lots of research online and from my understanding i think my query is ok
That is why i need your help to point me out what im doing wrong.

### What My Query Should Do

My query should fetch our stock level from both warehouse

### Problem Is

if the product is not in both warehouse the query dont give any result.

Ok so first i have two database of warehouse stock level. that look like that.

### Databases

```
-warehouse1
-warehouse2
```

### Table

```
-product
```

### Columns

```
-id
-SKU
-qty
```

So my Query is

```
SELECT
    warehouse1.product.id as 1_id,
    warehouse2.product.id as 2_id ,
    warehouse1.product.SKU,
    warehouse1.product.qty as 1_qty,
    warehouse2.product.qty as 2_qty
FROM `warehouse1`.`product`
    LEFT JOIN `warehouse2`.`product`
    ON
        (`warehouse1`.`product`.`SKU` = `warehouse2`.`product`.`SKU`)
    WHERE
        warehouse1.product.SKU = '$sku'
        OR
        warehouse2.product.SKU = '$sku'
ORDER BY
    (1_qty + 2_qty) DESC
```

if i make the `where` clause like this

```
WHERE warehouse1.product.SKU = '$sku'
```

it is then working but i can't get stock from both warehouse.

What should i do if i want to receive the stock level from both warehouse even if there is no product that im asking for in this database.

Thanks

Comment: try  select this also `warehouse2.product.SKU`

Comment: Try `Full Outer Join`

Comment: There is no `full outer join` in MySQL. I suspect the best solution is to use a `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. You're using a `LEFT JOIN`. That requires that the DB fetch all records that match your WHERE clause on the `LEFT` side of the join, which is warehouse1, and any potentially matching records from warehouse2 (the right side of the join). If a SKU exists only in warehouse2, you don't see it.

Switching to a FULL OUTER JOIN forces the DB to fetch all matching records from BOTH sides of the join, regardless of which side(s) the matching records exist on.

Comment: If i try A FULL OUTER JOIN i am given an error witch is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN

Comment: There is no FULL OUTER JOIN in MySQL

Comment: Is it possible that i have a older version that dont support full outer then ?

Comment: @MarcB Notice the status field:  "Status: Un-Assigned"

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this with a union

```
(SELECT
  warehouse1.product.id as 1_id,
  warehouse1.product.SKU,
  warehouse1.product.qty as 1_qty
FROM `warehouse1`.`product`
WHERE
    warehouse1.product.SKU = '$sku' )
  union
(SELECT
  warehouse2.product.id as 2_id ,
  warehouse2.product.SKU,
  warehouse2.product.qty as 2_qty
 FROM `warehouse2`.`product`
WHERE warehouse2.product.SKU = '$sku' )
```

Answer (score -1):

Combine your OR's in () (... OR ...):

```
SELECT
    warehouse1.product.id as 1_id,
    warehouse2.product.id as 2_id ,
    warehouse1.product.SKU,
    warehouse1.product.qty as 1_qty,
    warehouse2.product.qty as 2_qty
FROM `warehouse1`.`product`
    LEFT JOIN `warehouse2`.`product`
    ON
        (`warehouse1`.`product`.`SKU` = `warehouse2`.`product`.`SKU`)
    WHERE (warehouse1.product.SKU = '$sku'
        OR
        warehouse2.product.SKU = '$sku')
ORDER BY
    (1_qty + 2_qty) DESC
```

Comment: Adding brackets to a **SINGLE** boolean condition does absolutely NOTHING.

Comment: Thanks for you input! but it does the same